# Format timestamp to "August 17, 2010 7:15 am"

Tags: php, mysql

How can I format timestamp, generated by MySQL into "August 17, 2010 7:15 am"?

Comment: @Marc B, I have looked at it. But that didn't do it. It might be me which makes an error or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
select date_format(yourdate, '%M %d, %Y %l:%i %p') yourNewDate
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f105a/5)

If you have multiple fields that you need to format, then you will still use the Date_format:

```
select date_format(yourdate1, '%M %d, %Y %l:%i %p') yourNewDate1,
  date_format(yourdate2, '%M %d, %Y %l:%i %p') yourNewDate2
from yourtable
```

Comment: Well. But I am selecting more than one columns in the database table? with `SELECT * FROM .....`, would this still work? If so, how should it be set up?

Comment: @MarkTopper you will have to apply the format to each field, see my edit

Comment: @MarkTopper you will replace the `yourdate1` with the names of your fields you want to format

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Got it to work.

Comment: @MarkTopper glad you got it working. :)

Answer (score 1):

try using [date_format](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) in mysql

```
 DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%M %d, %Y %h:%i %p')
```

Query eg:

```
  select date_format(date_field, '%M %d, %Y %l:%i %p') as new_date
  from your_table
```

Comment: `select * from...` selects all columns, but since you want only this one column in a specific format, you would need to specify the other columns you want to select like `select col1, col2,...date_format(..) from..` else if you want multiple columns in that format, you need to do `select date_format(col1, ...), date_format(col2,...), date_format(..) from...`

Answer (score 1):

`date("U",$timestamp)` comes close to formatting it as you were wanting. If you want something closer you are going to have to build the date formatting string. Probably something like this `date("F j, Y g:i a", $timestamp)`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the transformation in PHP

```
$date = date("F d, Y g:i a", $timestampFromMySQL);
```

Comment: Well. It doesn't seems to work.. Gives me errors:  
Also my timestamp is like `2012-10-02 21:58:12`  
  
I get the following errors:
`Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\wamp\www\marktopper\blog_post.php on line 48`

Comment: wrap it in `strtotime()` like this: `strtotime($timestampFromMySQL)`